# zephir_parser extension not loaded

Tags: compilation, zephir

I'm running on ubuntu 14.04 and I installed php5.6. I'm trying to do the Hello world with [Zephir](https://docs.zephir-lang.com/en/latest/tutorial.html) but when I compile my project with :

```
zephir build
```

I got this error :

```
zephir_parser extension not loaded, compiling it
Parser statistics: 127 terminals, 99 nonterminals, 459 rules
                   947 states, 0 parser table entries, 0 conflicts
Parser statistics: 127 terminals, 99 nonterminals, 459 rules
                   947 states, 0 parser table entries, 0 conflicts
make: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop.
Preparing for parser compilation...
sh: 1: phpize: not found
sh: 1: ./configure: not found
Compiling the parser...
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.


PHP Warning:  copy(modules/zephir_parser.so): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /root/zephir/Library/Compiler.php on line 282
Zephir\Exception: The zephir parser extension could not be found or compiled!
```

Any idea ?

**Edit**

I reinstalled these packages :

```
php5-json php5-dev libpcre3-dev
```

I tried this command line :

```
./bin/zephir compile
```

And while compiling I have another error :

```
Copying new kernel files...
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function Zephir\utf8_decode() in /root/zephir/Library/Compiler.php on line 2202
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by reinstalling php with `libpcre3-dev` and install this :

```
apt-get install php5.6-xml
```

to solve the fatal error on the utf8_decode()